# A question about rigid objects in monoidal categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories, abelian-categories

Let $(\mathcal{A},\otimes,1_{\mathcal{A}})$ be a monoidal category, and let $M$ be a rigid object of $M$, with left and right dual respectively denoted by
$$
\Big\{M^*,~~~ \epsilon_l:M^* \otimes M \to 1_{\mathcal{A}},~~~ \eta_l:1_{\mathcal{A}} \to M \otimes M^*\Big\}
$$
and
$$
\Big\{{}^*M, ~~~\epsilon_r: M \otimes {}^*M \to 1_{\mathcal{A}},~~~\eta_r: 1_{\mathcal{A}} \to {}^*M \otimes M\Big\}
$$
respectively (just as in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigid_category) $\epsilon$ denotes **evaluation** and $\eta$ the **coevaluation**). Let's assume that we have isomorphisms $f_l:M \to M^*$ and $f_r:M \to {}^*M$. Then do we have the identity
$$
(\mathrm{id} \otimes f_l^{-1}) \circ \eta_l(1_{\mathcal{A}}) = (f_r^{-1} \otimes \mathrm{id}) \circ \eta_r(1_{\mathcal{A}})?
$$
This works for finite dimensional vector spaces, so I have guessed that it works in general. Also, do we have the identities
$$
\epsilon_l \circ (f_l \otimes \mathrm{id}) = \epsilon_r \circ (\mathrm{id} \otimes f_r): M \otimes M \to 1_{\mathcal{A}}?
$$

Comment: I guess you swapped X and M. Not evolution but evaluation. What is $f$? Can you specify the object for every morphism ($\mathrm{id}$, $\eta$, $\epsilon$)?

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux: Thanks you for seeing the typos! I have tried to fix them all and to specify the objects for $\epsilon$ and $\eta$.

Comment: The notation $M$ cannot be used for both the object and the category.

Comment: Good point! I will fix it.

Comment: Do you have any relation between $f_l$ and $f_r$ ? Otherwise it's clearly wrong (also for f.d. vector spaces), unless I'm missing something. Then this is typically the sort of questions where you want to use graphical calculus (if you're a newcomer in the world of rigid monoidal categories and haven't heard of graphical calculus yet, I strongly suggest you look it up !)

Comment: @Adrien: What kind of relationship between $f_l$ and $f_r$ are you suggesting? Also thank you for suggestion about graphical calculus!

Comment: There are at least two $M$ which should be $\mathcal{A}$, and for the second identity you should swap the composition for making sense, and then it is not a morphism from $M \otimes M$, but you should put appropriate dual.

Comment: Using the definition of evaluation and coevaluation maps (zigzag relations), your first identity is equivalent to $f_r^* = f_l$.

Comment: @Sebastien Palcoux: thanks a lot for comment. Could you explain this in more detail?

Comment: It is almost immediate using graphical calculus, so you need to learn that. You can read Sections 2 and 7 of my paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.06522 or watch my course of current semester on YouTube, from Session 3 at 15:00, https://youtu.be/zJvNsVUybKE ; and from Session 10 at 43:00 https://youtu.be/98lkVDT7hIo

Comment: Ok, thanks for the links!

Comment: If somebody would like to present this discussion as a formal answer, then I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: Maybe remove the false claim in your question? (It clearly doesn't hold for all isomorphisms, just consider $\lambda \cdot f_r$ for example.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is a graphical calculus:

[image]

For more details, you can read Sections 2 and 7 of my preprint [arxiv:2203.06522](https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.06522) or watch my course of current semester on YouTube, from Session 3 at 15:00 [here](https://youtu.be/zJvNsVUybKE), and from Session 10 at 43:00 [there](https://youtu.be/98lkVDT7hIo).

Comment: Really great, thanks a lot!